# Is this code thread and sync safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I need an authentication token to be thread and sync safe. The token will expire every hour and so a new one will need to be created and assigned to my static variable (TOKEN)

Will this do the trick?

Thanks,

```
    public static volatile string TOKEN = string.Empty;
    public static DateTime TOKEN_TIME = DateTime.Now;
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new object(); 

    public static string Get()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TOKEN))
        {
            if (!TokenIsValid())
            {
                lock(syncRoot)
                    TOKEN = CreateNewToken();
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            lock(syncRoot)
                TOKEN = CreateNewToken();
        }

        return TOKEN;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that code isn't thread-safe. Since the lock occurs inside the if statements, it is possible for two threads to create a token at roughly the same time. Consider the following:

- Thread 1 enters `else` block
- *Thread 1 yields to Thread 2*
- Thread 2 enters `else` block
- Thread 2 takes lock on `syncRoot`, creates a new token (token A), and assigns it to `TOKEN`
- Thread 2 returns "token A".
- *Thread 2 yields to Thread 1*
- Thread 1 takes lock on `syncRoot`, creates a new token (token B), and assigns it to `TOKEN`
- Thread 1 returns "token B".

Your system is now using two different tokens that were created only moments apart, and `Thread` references "token B".

**Edit:**
You can make your code threadsafe by taking a lock before you even check the token. The example below locks on every call to `Get()`, so it won't create two tokens at (almost) the same time like your code. There are also other locking patterns you can use, some of which may give better performance.

```
public static string Get()
{
    lock(syncRoot)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TOKEN) || !TokenIsValid())
            TOKEN = CreateNewToken();
        return TOKEN;
    }
}
```

Comment: The same scenario can occur for `if` branch too. And as a solution I would offer to wrap the whole `Get()` body with one lock.

Comment: An example of better performance (while still just using `lock`) is to use double-checked locking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking.  Read through the caveats there, though.